# What does 'as' mean in R?

Tags: r, variables, abbreviation

what does `as` mean in

```
as.numeric(T)
```

or

```
variable <- as.data.frame('midwest')`
```

P.S. explaining abbreviation would be much better if you please...

Comment: quite like its meaning in english — give me some value but *as* a different type of value. e.g. “give me (the data in) this list, but *as* a data frame.” or “give me that piece of paper, but *as* a paper airplane.” or: keep the info the same to the degree possible, but change the vehicle it’s delivered in.

Comment: u sure about that? is it a presumption?

Comment: @HoggyStardust ????? What do you mean “a presumption”. Honestly, read `?as`! This question should be closed because too broad and zero effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that you want an object to be converted to another one of a given type.

If I have `x <- 1` it is an numeric and thus, it has numeric properties (e.g. can be summed to 1 an become 2 as in `x + 1`). When you use `as.character(x)`, you basically transform that 1 (numeric) in a "1", which is an object of type "string". And so on. You can transform matrices to data frames with `as.data.frame()` and the opposite with `as.matrix()`, for example.

Hope this helps.